# Moving cursor position to a certain ID

Tags: sql, android

My user can flick through a set of records. I save the last seen record _ID in Preferences, so that they can start off from where they left when they access the application next time.

The cursor that I have extracts _ID field too. However, I don't know how to move cursor to that particular row. The following functions of the cursor need a specific postion to go to :-

*moveToPosition(int position)

move(int offset)*

The _ID may not be sequential (due to deletes etc).

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just have two queries, one for NextEmployee

```
SELECT MIN(RecordId) WHERE RecordId > currentRecordId
```

and one for PreviousEmployee

```
SELECT MAX(RecordId) WHERE RecordId < currentRecordId
```

and then call moveToPosition with the results?

I'm also confused as to why you're using a cursor, why don't you just fetch based off the recordId?

Comment: Mike, I plan to extract a bunch of records at a time. The reason is that the user will be viewing a number of records at a time (one after the other), so I don't want to do a database query for each record. I want to get a bunch and store it locally in a cursor so when the user presses "Next" and "Previous" buttons, I can just move the cursor position & display record, instead of database query. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and I have thought about **creating a HashMap with the _id as the keys and the positions in the Cursor as the values**.

To create this dictionary I have to iterate over all the elements of the Cursor once and then I will know the position of each _id inside the Cursor (having in mind that it can not be modified concurrently or I would retrieve the wrong data).

Do you think this is a right approach?